# Javascript function returning '[object Object]' instead of hash

Tags: javascript, function, hash

I have a function for picking out the parts of an entered name:

```
  function getNameParts(list) {
    first_name = list[0];
    middle_name = "";
    last_name = list[1];
    if(list.length > 2) {
      middle_name = list[1];
      last_name = list[2];
    }
    names = {"first": first_name, "middle": middle_name, "last": last_name};
    console.log("names", names)
    return names
  }
```

The console states that `names` is a hash inside this function.

But when I use this function like this:

```
name = getNameParts($("#person_name").val().split(' '));
console.log("name", name)
```

`name` is a string "[object Object]"

What's up with this?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, because [object Object] is what I would expect.  `names` is an object in your code.

Comment: I'm asking because [object Object] is a string and not a hash object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one;

```
function getNameParts(list) {
    var first_name = list[0];
   var middle_name = "";
    var last_name = list[1];
    if(list.length > 2) {
      middle_name = list[1];
      last_name = list[2];
    }
    var names = {"first": first_name, "middle": middle_name, "last": last_name};
    console.log("names", names)
    return names
  }
```

/// declare name varible

```
var name = getNameParts($("#person_name").val().split(' '));
console.log("name", name)
```

Comment: Nice! Yep this was the problem, thanks! I tend to forget to declare my variables, because I mostly program in ruby and coffeescript.

Answer (score 3):

Use JSON.stringify()

```
console.log('names', JSON.stringify(names));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1):

Is it really a string? You return an object from your function.

Try the following sample:

```
name = getNameParts($("#person_name").val().split(' '));
console.log("first", name.first);
console.log("middle", name.middle);
console.log("last", name.last);
```

You can access each of the properties values. When you try to parse an entire object to string it returns "[object Object]", as expected.

Comment: I've done this, just didn't include it in the question. I get `undefined` for each part of the hash. In my code I even made name into window.name to see what methods I could do to it and all the autocomplete methods are String type methods

Answer (score 0):

`name` is not a string. It is an object so when you are logging this value in console instead of ideally showing you the contents of the object, it is showing it's type which is console.

To verify this, you can log `names.first` or any other property in it

Answer (score 0):

`name` is an object, but when you use vendor-specific `console.log` function, it may try to coerce its arguments to string depending on how this particular environment programmers implemented it. `Object`'s default [stringification method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is to return `[object Object]`, which is exactly what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, it seems to be working just fine:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      function getNameParts(list) {
            var first_name = list[0],
                middle_name = "",
                last_name = list[1],
                names;

            if(list.length > 2) {
                middle_name = list[1];
                last_name = list[2];
            }
            names = {"first": first_name, "middle": middle_name, "last": last_name};
            console.log(names)
            return names;
        }

        var testString = "aaa bbb ccc";
        var name = getNameParts(testString.split(' '));
        console.log(name);

        console.log(name.first + " " + name.middle + " " + name.last);

   });
```

When you do console.log, if you do console.log("name" + names) and names is an object, it will show you the typeof names that is [object Object] instead of it's contents. For strings and numbers is alright to do it like that.